# NSImageview does not display jpg - storyboard - swift4

Tags: swift, imageview

I am trying to load an image into a imageView (inside NSWindow) but it does not work. The new window appears well but the image inside does not. I have try several ways to solve this problem (using URL instead of string for example) but they all failed. Could someone help me to find the right method?
P.S. the image as been inserted into xcassets and also added into the project (so I could make an URL out of it). Thanks

```
let imageView = NSImageView()
let image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("PageAide"))
imageView.image = image!

let window = NSWindow()
window.styleMask = NSWindow.StyleMask(rawValue: 0xf)
window.setFrame(NSRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 800, height: 800), display: false)
window.contentView?.addSubview(imageView)

let controller = NSWindowController(window: window)
controller.showWindow(self)
```

Comment: You aren't setting imageView's frame.  So where is it supposed to appear with what size?

Comment: It worked by adding the following line of code : imageView.frame = NSRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 800, height: 800). The only problem left is that it is not centered inside de windows. But, anyway, this problem is solved, thanks a lot.

Comment: My mystake. Corrected by changing abscisse and ordinate to "0" : imageView.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 800). My question received a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Final code :

```
let imageView = NSImageView()
let image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("Name of image has displayed in Assets.xcassets"))
imageView.image = image!
imageView.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 800)

let window = NSWindow()
window.styleMask = NSWindow.StyleMask(rawValue: 0xf)
window.setFrame(NSRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 800, height: 800), display: false)
window.contentView?.addSubview(imageView)

let controller = NSWindowController(window: window)
controller.showWindow(self)
```